# XOR Using Filter Logic

Tags: filters

Is making an XOR through Filter Logic possible?

I'm comparing opportunities by a custom field that is basically a date range. This field is called Selling Period and follows the format *year* - *season*. In this question I will be trying to compare 2018 - Spring and 2019 - Spring.

For ease of explanation: 
A = **2018 - Spring** AND **Stage = Closed**
B = **2019 - Spring**

I wish to compare Closed Opportunities from Previous Year to created opportunities from Current Year. Opportunities are linked back to the same Account.

How can I set-up the filter Logic to produce the result
A XOR B      and
A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XOR operation can be decomposed into combinations of AND, OR, and NOT.

```
A XOR B
```

becomes

```
(A OR B) AND NOT(A AND B)
```

That is, it's true if either A and B is true, but not both.

Comment: Perfect, that simplifies the XOR for me however it doesn't seem to end up with the result I want. I am currently just displaying the results in their entirety instead of displaying just B and it doesn't seem to have filtered correctly. 

With A and B both being under the same account, I want to display A only if B does not exist; in that there is no 2019 - Spring Opportunity created while there is a
 Closed 2018 - Spring Opportunity. This works for display purposes as it only shows A, however when I go back to the parent account, I see that B exists as well which means I have it wrong

Comment: @jphips What you're asking for (and what you probably should have put in your initial question, it was a bit fuzzy) can't be done directly in a report. I'm not saying it's not possible, but you'd have to have a rollup summary to count the opportunity data at the account level, then you could write a filter on the account data.

Comment: Shoot that's what I was worried about. Sorry I'm not completely clear on the terminology I should be using or really how to accurately ask this question. I need to phrase it properly and submit a request to the admin to see if they can build a formula to figure this out. Thanks for the input

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, what you want is something like a cross filter against other Opportunities on the same Account. Like sfdcfox says, that's not possible in a report (or with a simple formula). You need a rollup on the Account, which you can then use as a simple filter in the Opportunity report, no XOR required.

Comment: That's exactly right. I would want to look at opportunities from the Account level, compare between the custom field selling period, and display Closed opportunities for a certain selling period ONLY if an opportunity for the other selling period does not exist.